# Prove that there is no retraction from $X$ to the image of a loop $\gamma(t)$

Tags: proof-verification, algebraic-topology

Let $X = S^1 \times D^2$, pick $x_0 \in X$. Suppose $\gamma$ is an embedded loop based at $x_0$ which represents an $n \in \mathbb{Z} = \pi_1(X)$ with $n \neq \pm1$. Prove that there is no retraction from $X$ to the image of $\gamma$.

My attempt at a proof:

Assume there is a retraction $r: X \rightarrow \gamma(t)$.

Then $r\circ i = Id_{\gamma(t)}$, where $i: \gamma(t) \rightarrow X$ is the inclusion map.

Then, looking at the homomorphisms induced on the fundamental groups, we have:

$r_{*}\circ i_{*}=(r\circ i)_{*} = Id_{\gamma(t)_*}$

So, we have $\pi_1(\gamma(t)) \cong \mathbb{Z}$,

and $i_{*}: \pi_1(\gamma(t)) \rightarrow \pi_1(X)$ where $i_{*}(1)=n$ where $1$ is a generator of $\pi_1(\gamma(t))$

Thus $r_*\circ i_*(1)=r_*(n)=r_*(1+1+....+1)=r_*(1)+....+r_*(1)=1$

Where the equality $r_*(1)+....+r_*(1)=1$ 
is because $r_{*}\circ i_{*}=(r\circ i)_{*} = Id_{\gamma(t)_*}$

But this is impossible, for $n$ things in $\pi_1(\gamma(t))$ to add up to 1. Thus we have a contraidction, and so there is no retraction $r: X \rightarrow \gamma(t)$

Comment: This looks correct. You didn’t really mention the case where it represents -1, but that case is identical.

Comment: There is one other thing (more important than the -1 case). You haven’t justified that $[\gamma]$ generates the fundamental group of the embedded circle. The argument is not hard, but you must fully use the fact that $\gamma$ is an embedding (you can’t get by just with the image being a circle).

Comment: $\gamma(t)$ an embedding so  $\gamma(t) \cong [0,1]/ ~$ where $ ~$ is an equivalence identifying endpoints

Comment: Yes, the image is a circle, but that doesn't show why $\gamma$ represents a generator of the fundamental group. For example, if $\alpha$ was the loop wrapping twice around the core circle the image of $\alpha$ is a circle, but $\alpha$ does not represent a generator of the fundamental group of the image of $\alpha$.

Comment: The difference in these two examples is that $\gamma$ is an embedding, so you should use that fact.

Comment: A hint is that you should consider the funny map $\gamma_*:\pi_1(S^1) \rightarrow \pi_1(im(\gamma))$.

Comment: basically just observe that it sends generator to generator so is an isomorphism?